# как правильно составить запрос jdbc update

Tags: java, jdbc

Есть код на обновление таблиц mysql
но что-то не могу разобраться с кавычками, смысл в том, что в таблицу users нужно заполнить столбец proclist переменной lp , где ip определяется из переменной ownip. ,столбец ip уже заполнен

```
String[] insert = {"UPDATE `users` SET `proclist` = `" + lp + " ` WHERE `ip` = `" + ownip + "`"};



 for (String sql : insert) {
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Comment: Нужно получаемые ошибки приводить в вопросе.

Comment: Для простых названий столбцов и полей использование обратного апострофа необязательно.

Comment: Вам уже советовали использовать Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окружите текстовые переменные одинарными кавычками, например:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("UPDATE `users` SET `proclist` = ' " + lp + " ' WHERE `ip` = ' " + ownip + " ' ");
```

Это связано с тем, что SQL ожидает, что строки будут окружены одинарными кавычками. Еще лучшей альтернативой было бы использование подготовленных запросов:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM` prices` WHERE `poster` =?");
Stmt.setString (1, плакат);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ();
```

Рекомендуется использовать PreparedStatement, поскольку способ создания запроса (путем объединения строк) позволяет злоумышленнику вводить произвольный код SQL в запрос, угрозу безопасности, известную как SQL-инъекция.

Comment: а если одна из переменных StringBuilder а не String?

Comment: @Drop метод toString вызови

Answer (score 0):

НЕ создавайте SQL-команды, конкатенируя строки. Я думал, что мы давно это пережили. Это очень плохая практика и очень хороший способ создать ошибки и позволить огромные дыры в безопасности в ваших приложениях. Создание операторов SQL путем конкатенации строк - это рецепт катастрофы и плохой привычки, которую нужно убить до ее формирования.

Создай подготовленный запрос, и в цикле устанавливай параметры и  выполняй запрос.
Также можно использовать `pstmt.addBatch(); pstmt.executeBatch();`

Пример

```
String sql = 
   "UPDATE GLOBALSETTINGS " + 
   "  SET settingValue = ? " + 
   "WHERE settingName = ?";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "40");
pstmt.setString(2, "SessionTTL");
pstmt.executeUpdate();

pstmt.setString(1, "20");
pstmt.setString(2, "MaxUsersActive");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: я на java не так давно пишу и половину из того, что вы написали не понял)
Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на документацию, в которой подробнее написано то, о чем вы говорите?

Comment: @Drop почему вы не приняли ответ, где написано про кавычки?

Comment: я думал тут можно несколько выбирать